# Cygwin not working on Windows 10 (even after added to system's PATH)

Tags: cygwin, windows-10

I recently downloaded and installed Cygwin on my 64-bit Windows 10 computer. I'd like to for Cygwin to work with the normal Windows command prompt. Per instructions I found online, I added the path to the Cygwin executable to my system's PATH:

Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables -> appended `;C:\cygwin64\bin` to system's Path

Unfortunately, Cygwin still doesn't work on Windows command prompt. Any suggestions?

Comment: clarify `doesn't work `. What you are trying what is the output and your expectation ?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to make use of all Cygwin functionality at the Windows command prompt.  Some limited use of commands -- specifically those commands that exist as binaries in the `C:\cygwin64\bin` directory, and don't rely on any kind of shell support -- will work.  But since your're not running a shell when you're in a Windows prompt, the associated support normally available to you in a Cygwin native command window will not be there.